# Laravel 5.1 / 5.3 by calling non Laravel package pimax/fb-messenger-php

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, facebook-messenger

I am looking to use a non laravel provider pimax/fb-messenger-php with Laravel.  The this package is used and works with PHP.  How do I define the provider for this in my laravel config?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use Laravel, I assume you are using Composer as well.

So get into your command-prompt and enter the following in your Laravel project directory:

```
composer require "pimax/fb-messenger-php"
```

That information is available from the [Pimax GitHub project](https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I know that you can add it to Laravel by composer but how do you call it?  Do I need to declare it in some config file or create a separate config?  how about routing and controllers.  I have used the the example they have on the github page but that is for a stand alone php script not Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Run :
composer require "pimax/fb-messenger-php"

Once its done . You can simply use the classes in your controller . There is no need to edit/change/add in config file.

In your controller use classes:

```
use pimax\FbBotApp;
use pimax\Menu\MenuItem;
use pimax\Menu\LocalizedMenu;
use pimax\Messages\Message;
use pimax\Messages\MessageButton;
use pimax\Messages\StructuredMessage;
use pimax\Messages\MessageElement;
use pimax\Messages\MessageReceiptElement;
use pimax\Messages\Address;
use pimax\Messages\Summary;
use pimax\Messages\Adjustment;
use pimax\Messages\AccountLink;
use pimax\Messages\ImageMessage;
use pimax\Messages\QuickReply;
use pimax\Messages\QuickReplyButton;
use pimax\Messages\SenderAction;
```

......

and then in your controller function just use the sdk normally:

```
$bot = new FbBotApp($token);
$bot->send(new Message($ids, 'This is a sample message.'));
```